# Add grid lines to canvas by creating custom shape with MVVM WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, mvvm, shapes

I want to switch my **code-behind** project to **MVVM** design., but I'm having a little trouble with this.

I have canvas panel and i want create grid lines as backround.

In Code behind  i am adding the grids line by line to canvas panel. First initializing, zooming, panning etc. functions is very fast .

These are Code-Behind codes that creating grids method.

```
private void CreateGridLines()
        {
            // draw lines
            for (int x = -4000; x <= 4000; x += 100)
            {
                Line verticalLine = new Line
                {
                    Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(0xFF, 0x66, 0x66, 0x66)),
                    X1 = x,
                    Y1 = -4000,
                    X2 = x,
                    Y2 = 4000,
                    StrokeThickness = 1,
                };
  canvas.Children.Add(verticalLine);
        
            }

            for (int y = -4000; y <= 4000; y += 100)
            {
                Line horizontalLine = new Line
                {
                    Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(0xFF, 0x66, 0x66, 0x66)),
                    X1 = -4000,
                    Y1 = y,
                    X2 = 4000,
                    Y2 = y,
                    StrokeThickness = 1,
                };

                canvas.Children.Add(horizontalLine);
            }
        }
```

In MVVM patern I create ObservableCollection to update UI dynamically.

I added all grids line by line. That is worked but the reactions of the  view have become very slow while first initializing, zooming, panning etc. functions.

A total of approximately 160 elements are added to the list just because of the grid lines.

Each time a line is added it raises events. So this makes app is heavy i guess. I tried BindingList but I couldn't get as much efficiency as a code-behind way.

So i decided to add grids to observable collection at once, not line by line.

I guess i have to create grids as a Custom Shape which is derived by System.Windows.Shapes then i will add this custom shape to observable collection.

Another option is creating Line[] array object and adding all grid lines to this array.

But I could not manage to do this.
Is there anyone who can guide me or give me different suggestions on this issue?

These are XAML codes :

```
<Window x:Class="CanvasSampleMvvm.View.MainView"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xaml/behaviors"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CanvasSampleMvvm.View"
        xmlns:model="clr-namespace:CanvasSampleMvvm.Model"
        xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:CanvasSampleMvvm.ViewModel"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainView" Height="450" Width="800">

    <Window.Resources>
        <vm:MainViewVM x:Key="vm"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid DataContext="{StaticResource vm}">

        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Shapes}">
            <ItemsControl.Resources>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type model:GridLines}">
                    <Line X1="{Binding From.X}" Y1="{Binding From.Y}"
               X2="{Binding To.X}" Y2="{Binding To.Y}"
                              Stroke="{Binding Stroke}" 
                              StrokeThickness="{Binding StrokeThickness}"
                              />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.Resources>
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                  
                        <Canvas ClipToBounds="True" Background="Transparent" DataContext="{StaticResource vm}">
                        
                    </Canvas>
                
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            
        </ItemsControl>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

These are ViewModel class codes:

```
public class MainViewVM : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public ObservableCollection<GridLines> Shapes { get; } = new ObservableCollection<GridLines>();
        public MainViewVM()
        {
            CreateGridLines();
        }
        private void CreateGridLines()
        {
            // draw lines
            for (int x = -4000; x <= 4000; x += 100)
            {
                Shapes.Add(new GridLines
                {
                    From = new Point(x, -4000),
                    To = new Point(x, 4000),
                    StrokeThickness = 1,
                    Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(0xFF, 0x66, 0x66, 0x66)),
                    

                });
            }

            for (int y = -4000; y <= 4000; y += 100)
            {
                Shapes.Add(new GridLines
                {
                    From = new Point(-4000, y),
                    To = new Point(4000, y),
                    StrokeThickness = 1,
                    Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(0xFF, 0x66, 0x66, 0x66)),
                });

            }
        }

        private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    }
```

This is model class:

```
public class GridLines
    {
        public Point From { get; set; }
        public Point To { get; set; }
        public double Opacity { get; set; }
        public Brush Stroke { get; set; }
        public double StrokeThickness { get; set; }
    }
```

**EDIT:**
I found the solution with using LineGeometry. I shared the codes below for those who have the same problem.

```
<Canvas x:Class="CanvasMVVM.View.UCs.Grids"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CanvasMVVM.View.UCs"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800" >
    <Grid Background="Black">
        
    </Grid>
    <Canvas.Background>
        <DrawingBrush Stretch="None" TileMode="Tile"
          Viewport="0,0 100,100" ViewportUnits="Absolute">
            <DrawingBrush.Drawing>
                <GeometryDrawing>
                    <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                        <GeometryGroup>
                            <LineGeometry StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,100"/>
                            <LineGeometry StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="100,0"/>
                        </GeometryGroup>
                    </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                    <GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                        <Pen Thickness="0.5" Brush="Black"/>
                    </GeometryDrawing.Pen>

                </GeometryDrawing>
            </DrawingBrush.Drawing>
        </DrawingBrush>
    </Canvas.Background>
</Canvas>
```

Comment: In the first place, if the lines are drawn just to fill the background of View, there is no good reason to provide each line's data from VM.

Comment: Why are you drawing the lines in view view model? Keep your view-related code in the views where it belongs. MVVM is not about eliminating code from the views. It's mainly about separation of concerns. And it's not the responsibility of a view model to draw the grid lines in a view.

Answer (score 1):

You must not draw visual effects from the View Model. The View Model only manages data presentation. If need to do some manual drawing move the code to the View (code-behind).

The following example uses a `Grid` to draw a raster. When you set `Grid.ShowGridLines` to `true` it shows dashed line separators. When you wrap both the raster `Grid` and the `Canvas` into a common `Grid` you can use overlaying (z-indexing). Basically, draw the transparent `Canvas` on top of the raster `Grid`.

The examples use XAML, but you can generate the raster `Grid` dynamically from code-behind.

The following examples draw a 6x6 raster as background for a 200x200 `Canvas`.

Using built-in gridlines of `Grid`:

```xml
<Grid Height="200"
      Width="200">
  <Grid.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="CanvasBackgroundBrush"
                     Color="Yellow"
                     Opacity="0.3" />
  </Grid.Resources>
  <Grid ShowGridLines="True"
        Background="Transparent">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition />
      <RowDefinition />
      <RowDefinition />
      <RowDefinition />
      <RowDefinition />
      <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition />
      <ColumnDefinition />
      <ColumnDefinition />
      <ColumnDefinition />
      <ColumnDefinition />
      <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
  </Grid>

  <Canvas Background="{StaticResource CanvasBackgroundBrush}">
    <Rectangle Width="50"
               Height="50"
               Canvas.Left="100"
               Canvas.Top="100"
               Fill="Orange" />
  </Canvas>
</Grid>
```

[image]

Using Border elements for a solid grid:

```xml
<Grid Height="200"
      Width="200">
  <Grid.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="GridLinesBrush"
                     Color="Black"
                     Opacity="0.2" />
    <Style TargetType="Border">
      <Setter Property="BorderBrush"
              Value="{StaticResource GridLinesBrush}" />
      <Setter Property="BorderThickness"
              Value="1" />
    </Style>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="CanvasBackgroundBrush"
                     Color="Yellow"
                     Opacity="0.3" />
  </Grid.Resources>
  <Grid Background="Transparent">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition />
      <RowDefinition />
      <RowDefinition />
      <RowDefinition />
      <RowDefinition />
      <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition />
      <ColumnDefinition />
      <ColumnDefinition />
      <ColumnDefinition />
      <ColumnDefinition />
      <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Border Grid.Row="0"
            Grid.ColumnSpan="6" />

    <Border Grid.Row="1"
            Grid.ColumnSpan="6" />

    <Border Grid.Row="2"
            Grid.ColumnSpan="6" />

    <Border Grid.Row="3"
            Grid.ColumnSpan="6" />

    <Border Grid.Row="4"
            Grid.ColumnSpan="6" />

    <Border Grid.Row="5"
            Grid.ColumnSpan="6" />

    <Border Grid.Column="0"
            Grid.RowSpan="6" />

    <Border Grid.Column="1"
            Grid.RowSpan="6" />

    <Border Grid.Column="2"
            Grid.RowSpan="6" />

    <Border Grid.Column="3"
            Grid.RowSpan="6" />

    <Border Grid.Column="4"
            Grid.RowSpan="6" />

    <Border Grid.Column="5"
            Grid.RowSpan="6" />
  </Grid>

  <Canvas Background="{StaticResource CanvasBackgroundBrush}">
    <Rectangle Width="50"
               Height="50"
               Canvas.Left="100"
               Canvas.Top="100"
               Fill="Orange" />
  </Canvas>
</Grid>
```

[image]

Comment: Thanx for attention. I figured out with using LineGeometry that i shared the codes in edited post.  I have also recorded the solution you gave as an alternative. Thanx again.